# IIS7 web.config file is not supporting redirects and 404 at the same time

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I have written an external redirect file for use in a site. The redirect works perfectly, but when I add a 404 rule, the redirect breaks. At that point, 404 works, but the redirect does not. I've also tried keeping the redirect rules inside of the web.config file (instead of as a separate file), but this does not work either.

Can anyone figure out how I can get my redirects and 404 rules working in tandem?

Below is the code for the redirect in the web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rewriteMaps configSource="rewritemaps.config" />
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect rule1 for Redirects">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                       <add input="{Redirects:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The external file referenced above looks like this:

```
<rewriteMaps>  
    <rewriteMap name="Redirects">  
        <add key="/old_page.html" value="/new_page.html" />  
    </rewriteMap>  
</rewriteMaps>
```

At this point everything works great. However, as soon as I add the following, the 404 works great, but the redirect does not work.

```
<httpErrors>
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/page-not-found.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

The total code that does not work is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rewriteMaps configSource="rewritemaps.config" />
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect rule1 for Redirects">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                       <add input="{Redirects:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpErrors>
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/page-not-found.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Working absolutely fine here. Try recycling app pool .. or restart IIS service

Comment: Son of a gun! That worked. Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your config is fine -- no issues here.

Try recycling app pool .. or restart IIS service.

Comment: And if that is not working: make sure you are actually using IIS!

What worked for me was going to the Project's Properties, select the Web tab, and changing "Use Visual Studio Development Server" to "Use local IIS Web server", and accepting the default sub-settings of (in my case) "Use IIS Express" and Project Url "http://localhost:52246/".